# How to load custom components in React from a different folder?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm thinking about moving my project to React but there is a road block.

Let me explain.

The project have components (now it's written in php). 
If you need to customize on of them you just need to extend the original class of a component and load it from a custom folder.

Example:

The components are located under this directory:
**/path/to/core/components/CustomerProfile**

If you need to customize something you need to use this directory:
**/path/to/custom/components/CustomerProfile**

How can I use custom Components in React (and load them from a custom folder)?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use relative paths while importing components e.g. `import { CustomComponent } from '../../../whatever-folder-you-need'` or what's the question here? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import {CustomComponent} from 'relative-path-to-customcomponent'
```

and do not forget to export the default component.

How to export :
Inside your component file,

```
export default ComponentName
```